# How to get the access token key and token secret key from linkedin api

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I have created and application in linkedin, so I got client-id and client-secret key.. I am not able to get access token and secret key from linked in.

How to get the access token and access token secret key from linkedIn?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried?

Comment: i went this link https://developer.linkedin.com/

Comment: i have created new app with  respected details and i got only two keys?

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Don't comment

Comment: Actually my aim is to get profile details from linkedIn by giving search keyword(linked in usernames) from keyboard.